# Why am I getting an error when sending a SOAP message with SOAP UI?

Tags: xml, soap

End point: `http://127.0.0.1:${#Project#Puerto}/DispatcherProxy`

SOAP Message:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:applicationStub2="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:applicationStub3="http://agr.intel.com/ApplicationServiceSoap" xmlns:applicationStub="http://agr.intel.com/" xmlns:applicationStub4="http://agr.intel.com/ApplicationServiceSoap1" xmlns:envStub="http://agr.intel.com/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <envStub:AuthHeader>
            <TestDataFlag>0</TestDataFlag>
            <envStub:ClientVersion>wi3.7.0.38738.81</envStub:ClientVersion>
        </envStub:AuthHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <applicationStub:SearchApplications>
            <applicationStub:UserId>0</applicationStub:UserId>
            <applicationStub:StoreId>2</applicationStub:StoreId>
            <applicationStub:LocaleCode>en-US</applicationStub:LocaleCode>
            <applicationStub:Location>US</applicationStub:Location>
            <applicationStub:CategoryId>272</applicationStub:CategoryId>
            <applicationStub:AlternativeLocales></applicationStub:AlternativeLocales>
            <applicationStub:Filters>
                <applicationStub:JoinType>AND</applicationStub:JoinType>
                <applicationStub:Filter>
                    <applicationStub:FilterField>AppType</applicationStub:FilterField>
                    <applicationStub:FilterOperator>=</applicationStub:FilterOperator>
                    <applicationStub:FilterValue>All</applicationStub:FilterValue>
                </applicationStub:Filter>
            </applicationStub:Filters>
            <applicationStub:ResultStart>1</applicationStub:ResultStart>
            <applicationStub:ResultNum>24</applicationStub:ResultNum>
            <applicationStub:OrderBy>Download</applicationStub:OrderBy>
            <applicationStub:OrderByType>Desc</applicationStub:OrderByType>
            <applicationStub:DeviceProfileBitmap>1,2,8</applicationStub:DeviceProfileBitmap>
        </applicationStub:SearchApplications>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer from server:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns3="http://Intel.ServicesManager.ServiceContracts" xmlns:ns1="http://Intel.ServicesManager.DispatcherProxy">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Validation constraint violation: tag name or namespace mismatch in element &lt;applicationStub:SearchApplications></faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The error is between the "faultstring" tags. The message is supposed to bring me a list of applications. Note that the SOAP message was taken from the SENT.log file that was generated when a library was copied.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a mapping for the `agr` namespace prefix that you use in your request.  Was the XML hand-generated?

Comment: The XML was generated with the SENT.log file. The message was taken from the log.

Comment: I have changed the message as it is in the SENT.log file, and the answer from server.